# Persist Product setData

Tags: magento2.4.0

I'm using the following code to try and **update a product's description**:

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById(5);
$product->setData('description', 'foo');
$this->productRepository->save($product, $saveOptions = false);
```

While the data does get saved
(I can fetch it correctly via `$product->getData('description');`),
it is not changed in the db and thus no changes in the actual description.
Are additional steps necessary or am I using a false approach entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns I was editing the wrong shop-language. Persisting the data actually worked the whole time.

It's a good idea to always use the storeId when getting the model-object form the repository.